# Cloud Firestore query with UID

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a subset of data based on the first letter of the name and also including the UID of the document.  Cannot seem to get it right.  Just
returns empty data.

```
getNames(firstletter: string) {
this.afs.collection('list' , ref => 
ref.orderBy('NAME').startAt(firstletter).endAt(firstletter+'\uf8ff'))
.snapshotChanges()    
.map(actions => {
 return actions.map(a => {
  const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
  const id = a.payload.doc.id;
  return { id, data };
})
})}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax from the Realtime Database. The [Cloud Firestore query syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) is:

```
ref.where('NAME', '>=', firstletter).where('NAME', '<=', firstletter+'\uf8ff'))
```